# Pontiac Aztek 2004 Oil Leak

Tags: pontiac, oil-leak

There is some leaking underneath the engine. My guess is that it's an [image]engine oil leak. Do you think I'm correct? From your experience, what is a good place to start looking for the leak? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: I'm interested in using the first photo here as an educational tool on cleaning up oil leaks or spills. Would that be okay and how would you like it credited? If you'd like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like oil - simplest place to start is to get the front jacked up, ideally on axle stands or a ramp to make it as safe as possible.

Get a good maintenance lamp and just start looking for oil - the shine gives it away, even amongst the dirt you get on the underside of the engine.

Check the drain valve for the oil pan/sump, and look for drips down the side of the engine block to check for leaks higher up.